# LINK error while i want to link glslang and SPIRV

Tags: glsl, vulkan, spir-v

I want to use glslang and SPIRV libraries for online glsl conversion and spirv generation, i was able to generate the project files through cmake and i was able to successfully Build the project glslang.sln, the building process yielded all the required libraries as well as the executables, however when i set up my VS project and try to link glslang and SPIRV i get the following link errors:

```
Severity    Code    Description Project File    Line    Suppression State
Error   LNK2001 unresolved external symbol "public: void __cdecl 
shader::initializeResources(struct TBuiltInResource &)" (? initializeResources@shader@@QEAAXAEAUTBuiltInResource@@@Z)   glslang-TO-SPV  C:\Users\Zirian\source\repos\glslang-TO-SPV\glslang-TO-SPV\shader.obj   1   
Error   LNK2001 unresolved external symbol spvContextCreate glslang-TO-SPV  C:\Users\Zirian\source\repos\glslang-TO-SPV\glslang-TO-SPV\SPIRV.lib(SpvTools.obj)  1   
Error   LNK2001 unresolved external symbol spvContextDestroy    glslang-TO-SPV  C:\Users\Zirian\source\repos\glslang-TO-SPV\glslang-TO-SPV\SPIRV.lib(SpvTools.obj)  1   
Error   LNK2001 unresolved external symbol spvValidatorOptionsCreate    glslang-TO-SPV  C:\Users\Zirian\source\repos\glslang-TO-SPV\glslang-TO-SPV\SPIRV.lib(SpvTools.obj)  1   
Error   LNK2001 unresolved external symbol spvValidatorOptionsDestroy   glslang-TO-SPV  C:\Users\Zirian\source\repos\glslang-TO-SPV\glslang-TO-SPV\SPIRV.lib(SpvTools.obj)  1   
Error   LNK2001 unresolved external symbol spvValidatorOptionsSetBeforeHlslLegalization glslang-TO-SPV  C:\Users\Zirian\source\repos\glslang-TO-SPV\glslang-TO-SPV\SPIRV.lib(SpvTools.obj)  1   
Error   LNK2001 unresolved external symbol spvValidatorOptionsSetRelaxBlockLayout   glslang-TO-SPV  C:\Users\Zirian\source\repos\glslang-TO-SPV\glslang-TO-SPV\SPIRV.lib(SpvTools.obj)  1   
Error   LNK2001 unresolved external symbol spvOptimizerOptionsCreate    glslang-TO-SPV  C:\Users\Zirian\source\repos\glslang-TO-SPV\glslang-TO-SPV\SPIRV.lib(SpvTools.obj)  1   
Error   LNK2001 unresolved external symbol spvOptimizerOptionsDestroy   glslang-TO-SPV  C:\Users\Zirian\source\repos\glslang-TO-SPV\glslang-TO-SPV\SPIRV.lib(SpvTools.obj)  1   
Error   LNK2001 unresolved external symbol spvOptimizerOptionsSetRunValidator   glslang-TO-SPV  C:\Users\Zirian\source\repos\glslang-TO-SPV\glslang-TO-SPV\SPIRV.lib(SpvTools.obj)  1   
Error   LNK2001 unresolved external symbol spvBinaryToText  glslang-TO-SPV  C:\Users\Zirian\source\repos\glslang-TO-SPV\glslang-TO-SPV\SPIRV.lib(SpvTools.obj)  1   
Error   LNK2001 unresolved external symbol spvValidateWithOptions   glslang-TO-SPV  C:\Users\Zirian\source\repos\glslang-TO-SPV\glslang-TO-SPV\SPIRV.lib(SpvTools.obj)  1   
Error   LNK2001 unresolved external symbol spvDiagnosticDestroy glslang-TO-SPV  C:\Users\Zirian\source\repos\glslang-TO-SPV\glslang-TO-SPV\SPIRV.lib(SpvTools.obj)  1   
Error   LNK2001 unresolved external symbol spvDiagnosticPrint   glslang-TO-SPV  C:\Users\Zirian\source\repos\glslang-TO-SPV\glslang-TO-SPV\SPIRV.lib(SpvTools.obj)  1   
Error   LNK2001 unresolved external symbol "public: __cdecl spvtools::Optimizer::PassToken::~PassToken(void)" (??1PassToken@Optimizer@spvtools@@QEAA@XZ)    glslang-TO-SPV  C:\Users\Zirian\source\repos\glslang-TO-SPV\glslang-TO-SPV\SPIRV.lib(SpvTools.obj)  1   
Error   LNK2001 unresolved external symbol "public: __cdecl spvtools::Optimizer::Optimizer(enum spv_target_env)" (??0Optimizer@spvtools@@QEAA@W4spv_target_env@@@Z) glslang-TO-SPV  C:\Users\Zirian\source\repos\glslang-TO-SPV\glslang-TO-SPV\SPIRV.lib(SpvTools.obj)  1   
Error   LNK2001 unresolved external symbol "public: __cdecl spvtools::Optimizer::~Optimizer(void)" (??1Optimizer@spvtools@@QEAA@XZ) glslang-TO-SPV  C:\Users\Zirian\source\repos\glslang-TO-SPV\glslang-TO-SPV\SPIRV.lib(SpvTools.obj)  1   
Error   LNK2001 unresolved external symbol "public: void __cdecl spvtools::Optimizer::SetMessageConsumer(class std::function<void __cdecl(enum spv_message_level_t,char const *,struct spv_position_t const &,char const *)>)" (?SetMessageConsumer@Optimizer@spvtools@@QEAAXV?$function@$$A6AXW4spv_message_level_t@@PEBDAEBUspv_position_t@@1@Z@std@@@Z)  glslang-TO-SPV  C:\Users\Zirian\source\repos\glslang-TO-SPV\glslang-TO-SPV\SPIRV.lib(SpvTools.obj)  1   
Error   LNK2001 unresolved external symbol "public: class spvtools::Optimizer & __cdecl spvtools::Optimizer::RegisterPass(struct spvtools::Optimizer::PassToken &&)" (?RegisterPass@Optimizer@spvtools@@QEAAAEAV12@$$QEAUPassToken@12@@Z)   glslang-TO-SPV  C:\Users\Zirian\source\repos\glslang-TO-SPV\glslang-TO-SPV\SPIRV.lib(SpvTools.obj)  1   
Error   LNK2001 unresolved external symbol "public: bool __cdecl spvtools::Optimizer::Run(unsigned int const *,unsigned __int64,class std::vector<unsigned int,class std::allocator<unsigned int> > *,struct spv_optimizer_options_t * const)const " (?Run@Optimizer@spvtools@@QEBA_NPEBI_KPEAV?$vector@IV?$allocator@I@std@@@std@@QEAUspv_optimizer_options_t@@@Z) glslang-TO-SPV  C:\Users\Zirian\source\repos\glslang-TO-SPV\glslang-TO-SPV\SPIRV.lib(SpvTools.obj)  1   
Error   LNK2001 unresolved external symbol "struct spvtools::Optimizer::PassToken __cdecl spvtools::CreateEliminateDeadFunctionsPass(void)" (?CreateEliminateDeadFunctionsPass@spvtools@@YA?AUPassToken@Optimizer@1@XZ) glslang-TO-SPV  C:\Users\Zirian\source\repos\glslang-TO-SPV\glslang-TO-SPV\SPIRV.lib(SpvTools.obj)  1   
Error   LNK2001 unresolved external symbol "struct spvtools::Optimizer::PassToken __cdecl spvtools::CreateBlockMergePass(void)" (?CreateBlockMergePass@spvtools@@YA?AUPassToken@Optimizer@1@XZ) glslang-TO-SPV  C:\Users\Zirian\source\repos\glslang-TO-SPV\glslang-TO-SPV\SPIRV.lib(SpvTools.obj)  1   
Error   LNK2001 unresolved external symbol "struct spvtools::Optimizer::PassToken __cdecl spvtools::CreateInlineExhaustivePass(void)" (?CreateInlineExhaustivePass@spvtools@@YA?AUPassToken@Optimizer@1@XZ) glslang-TO-SPV  C:\Users\Zirian\source\repos\glslang-TO-SPV\glslang-TO-SPV\SPIRV.lib(SpvTools.obj)  1   
Error   LNK2001 unresolved external symbol "struct spvtools::Optimizer::PassToken __cdecl spvtools::CreateLocalSingleBlockLoadStoreElimPass(void)" (?CreateLocalSingleBlockLoadStoreElimPass@spvtools@@YA?AUPassToken@Optimizer@1@XZ)   glslang-TO-SPV  C:\Users\Zirian\source\repos\glslang-TO-SPV\glslang-TO-SPV\SPIRV.lib(SpvTools.obj)  1   
Error   LNK2001 unresolved external symbol "struct spvtools::Optimizer::PassToken __cdecl spvtools::CreateDeadBranchElimPass(void)" (?CreateDeadBranchElimPass@spvtools@@YA?AUPassToken@Optimizer@1@XZ) glslang-TO-SPV  C:\Users\Zirian\source\repos\glslang-TO-SPV\glslang-TO-SPV\SPIRV.lib(SpvTools.obj)  1   
Error   LNK2001 unresolved external symbol "struct spvtools::Optimizer::PassToken __cdecl spvtools::CreateLocalMultiStoreElimPass(void)" (?CreateLocalMultiStoreElimPass@spvtools@@YA?AUPassToken@Optimizer@1@XZ)   glslang-TO-SPV  C:\Users\Zirian\source\repos\glslang-TO-SPV\glslang-TO-SPV\SPIRV.lib(SpvTools.obj)  1   
Error   LNK2001 unresolved external symbol "struct spvtools::Optimizer::PassToken __cdecl spvtools::CreateLocalAccessChainConvertPass(void)" (?CreateLocalAccessChainConvertPass@spvtools@@YA?AUPassToken@Optimizer@1@XZ)   glslang-TO-SPV  C:\Users\Zirian\source\repos\glslang-TO-SPV\glslang-TO-SPV\SPIRV.lib(SpvTools.obj)  1   
Error   LNK2001 unresolved external symbol "struct spvtools::Optimizer::PassToken __cdecl spvtools::CreateLocalSingleStoreElimPass(void)" (?CreateLocalSingleStoreElimPass@spvtools@@YA?AUPassToken@Optimizer@1@XZ) glslang-TO-SPV  C:\Users\Zirian\source\repos\glslang-TO-SPV\glslang-TO-SPV\SPIRV.lib(SpvTools.obj)  1   
Error   LNK2001 unresolved external symbol "struct spvtools::Optimizer::PassToken __cdecl spvtools::CreateDeadInsertElimPass(void)" (?CreateDeadInsertElimPass@spvtools@@YA?AUPassToken@Optimizer@1@XZ) glslang-TO-SPV  C:\Users\Zirian\source\repos\glslang-TO-SPV\glslang-TO-SPV\SPIRV.lib(SpvTools.obj)  1   
Error   LNK2001 unresolved external symbol "struct spvtools::Optimizer::PassToken __cdecl spvtools::CreateAggressiveDCEPass(void)" (?CreateAggressiveDCEPass@spvtools@@YA?AUPassToken@Optimizer@1@XZ)   glslang-TO-SPV  C:\Users\Zirian\source\repos\glslang-TO-SPV\glslang-TO-SPV\SPIRV.lib(SpvTools.obj)  1   
Error   LNK2001 unresolved external symbol "struct spvtools::Optimizer::PassToken __cdecl spvtools::CreatePropagateLineInfoPass(void)" (?CreatePropagateLineInfoPass@spvtools@@YA?AUPassToken@Optimizer@1@XZ)   glslang-TO-SPV  C:\Users\Zirian\source\repos\glslang-TO-SPV\glslang-TO-SPV\SPIRV.lib(SpvTools.obj)  1   
Error   LNK2001 unresolved external symbol "struct spvtools::Optimizer::PassToken __cdecl spvtools::CreateRedundantLineInfoElimPass(void)" (?CreateRedundantLineInfoElimPass@spvtools@@YA?AUPassToken@Optimizer@1@XZ)   glslang-TO-SPV  C:\Users\Zirian\source\repos\glslang-TO-SPV\glslang-TO-SPV\SPIRV.lib(SpvTools.obj)  1   
Error   LNK2001 unresolved external symbol "struct spvtools::Optimizer::PassToken __cdecl spvtools::CreateCFGCleanupPass(void)" (?CreateCFGCleanupPass@spvtools@@YA?AUPassToken@Optimizer@1@XZ) glslang-TO-SPV  C:\Users\Zirian\source\repos\glslang-TO-SPV\glslang-TO-SPV\SPIRV.lib(SpvTools.obj)  1   
Error   LNK2001 unresolved external symbol "struct spvtools::Optimizer::PassToken __cdecl spvtools::CreateMergeReturnPass(void)" (?CreateMergeReturnPass@spvtools@@YA?AUPassToken@Optimizer@1@XZ)   glslang-TO-SPV  C:\Users\Zirian\source\repos\glslang-TO-SPV\glslang-TO-SPV\SPIRV.lib(SpvTools.obj)  1   
Error   LNK2001 unresolved external symbol "struct spvtools::Optimizer::PassToken __cdecl spvtools::CreateRedundancyEliminationPass(void)" (?CreateRedundancyEliminationPass@spvtools@@YA?AUPassToken@Optimizer@1@XZ)   glslang-TO-SPV  C:\Users\Zirian\source\repos\glslang-TO-SPV\glslang-TO-SPV\SPIRV.lib(SpvTools.obj)  1   
Error   LNK2001 unresolved external symbol "struct spvtools::Optimizer::PassToken __cdecl spvtools::CreateScalarReplacementPass(unsigned int)" (?CreateScalarReplacementPass@spvtools@@YA?AUPassToken@Optimizer@1@I@Z)  glslang-TO-SPV  C:\Users\Zirian\source\repos\glslang-TO-SPV\glslang-TO-SPV\SPIRV.lib(SpvTools.obj)  1   
Error   LNK2001 unresolved external symbol "struct spvtools::Optimizer::PassToken __cdecl spvtools::CreateIfConversionPass(void)" (?CreateIfConversionPass@spvtools@@YA?AUPassToken@Optimizer@1@XZ) glslang-TO-SPV  C:\Users\Zirian\source\repos\glslang-TO-SPV\glslang-TO-SPV\SPIRV.lib(SpvTools.obj)  1   
Error   LNK2001 unresolved external symbol "struct spvtools::Optimizer::PassToken __cdecl spvtools::CreateSimplificationPass(void)" (?CreateSimplificationPass@spvtools@@YA?AUPassToken@Optimizer@1@XZ) glslang-TO-SPV  C:\Users\Zirian\source\repos\glslang-TO-SPV\glslang-TO-SPV\SPIRV.lib(SpvTools.obj)  1   
Error   LNK2001 unresolved external symbol "struct spvtools::Optimizer::PassToken __cdecl spvtools::CreateVectorDCEPass(void)" (?CreateVectorDCEPass@spvtools@@YA?AUPassToken@Optimizer@1@XZ)   glslang-TO-SPV  C:\Users\Zirian\source\repos\glslang-TO-SPV\glslang-TO-SPV\SPIRV.lib(SpvTools.obj)  1   
Error   LNK1120 39 unresolved externals glslang-TO-SPV  C:\Users\Zirian\source\repos\glslang-TO-SPV\x64\Release\glslang-TO-SPV.exe  1
```

the libraries that i am using are `SPIRV.lib glslang.lib OGLCompiler.lib OSDependent.lib HLSL.lib`

my library folder contains the following libraries:

[image]

Iam using VS 2019 platform x64